# Some input boxes are not cleared on the second click Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Dears, I made a javascript function when checkbox is checked to enable some controllers and when unchecked disable the same controllers and clear their data, it works fine in the first click only, which means if I check the checkbox and select data, then unchecked the checkbox it clear data from input boxes and hide the datetimepicker. BUT if check the checkbox for the second time and select data, then unchecked the checkbox, it does not clear data but hide the time picker.

HTML

```
 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 margin-bottom-10 padding-none">
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-check margin-top-30">
                                            <label>
                                                <input ng-model="attend" type="checkbox" name="check" ng-change="checkattendance()"> <span class="label-text">Attendance Time</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            <label class="control-label" for="name">Operator<span class="danger">*</span></label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            <select ng-disabled="!attend" ng-show="lang==0" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="opinname" ng-options="o.opid as o.openm for o in Operator"></select>
                                            <select ng-disabled="!attend" ng-show="lang==1" class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="opinname" ng-options="o.opid as o.opanm for o in Operator"></select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            <label class="control-label" for="name">From <span class="danger">*</span></label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 date">
                                            <div id="timeform1" class="input-append date">
                                                <input data-format="hh:mm:ss" type="text" class="form-control" ng-disabled="!attend" ng-model="from2">
                                                <span class="add-on" >
                                                    <i data-time-icon="icon-time"id="icon1" data-date-icon="icon-calendar" ng-show="attend">
                                                    </i>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            <label class="control-label" for="name">To <span class="danger">*</span></label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 date">
                                            <div id="timeto1" class="input-append date">
                                                <input data-format="hh:mm:ss" type="text" class="form-control" ng-disabled="!attend" ng-model="to2">
                                                <span class="add-on">
                                                    <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar" ng-show="attend">
                                                    </i>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Angular js

```
$scope.checkattendance = function () {
        if ($scope.attend == true) {

            $('#timeform1').datetimepicker({
                pickTime: true, pickDate: false
            });
            $('#timeto1').datetimepicker({
                pickTime: true, pickDate: false
            });
        }
        else  {
            $scope.opinname = '';
            $scope.from2 = '';
            $scope.to2 = '';
            $scope.apply();

        }

    }
```

why ng-model=from2 and ng-model=to2 are not binded and clear the data
any help , thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that your current checkattendance function is not changing the attend boolean, it needs to toggle the state from true to false or false to true each time the checkbox is changed, one easy modification is to modify the function and add `$scope.attend =!$scope.attend;` either at the start or the end of the function. Something like below:

```
$scope.checkattendance = function () {
    $scope.attend =!$scope.attend;
    if ($scope.attend == true) {

        $('#timeform1').datetimepicker({
            pickTime: true, pickDate: false
        });
        $('#timeto1').datetimepicker({
            pickTime: true, pickDate: false
        });
    }
    else  {
        $scope.opinname = '';
        $scope.from2 = '';
        $scope.to2 = '';
        $scope.apply();

    }

}
```

You should also tie the checkbox's selected state to that boolean something like `checked=attend`

Comment: how to tie the checbox selected state, do you mean ng-checked=attend , i wrote the code but it does not allow me to click on the check box, any idea

Comment: Yes, `ng-checked="attend"` . See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

Comment: unfortunately it is still not working, the checkbox now is not clickable after these changes, any help